# Apply property to all but but last component in template

Tags: ember.js

I'm pretty new to Ember.js so I'm wondering if anyone might know of a "clever" way to accomplish this.

I have several instances of a component I am rendering in a template representing steps in a process. I'd like to set a boolean property (collapse) on all of them except for the last one. I could do this by hand using computed properties (see example below), but this would be onerous because each step in the process would have different (sometimes multiple) conditions for this boolean property to be set, and would become harder to maintain the larger this part of my code base gets.

This is what that would look like:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{event-box collapse=wasBCompleted}}</li>
  ...
  <li>{{event-box collapse=wasCAndDCompleted}}</li>
  ...
  <li>{{event-box collapse=false}}</li>
</ul>
```

I was hoping there might be a way to select (or track) all instances of a component in a template and apply the property to them in one step - or maybe add them to an Array as I put them in the template and then iterate over that later, but I haven't been able to successfully do this yet.

Can anyone suggest if this is viable? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clear up your question a little bit; what are you trying to accomplish?

Apply a property to all but last component in a template? Easy! But I don't think it's what you're really looking for.

```
<ul>
  <li>{{event-box collapse=wasBCompleted}}</li>
  ...
  <li>{{event-box collapse=wasCAndDCompleted}}</li>
  ...
  <li>{{event-box}}</li>
</ul>
```

What is the event-box component trying to do? More specifically, what information does it need from the outside (in this example, the 'collapse' property) in order to do its job?

Comment: event-box displays text in a consistent style and includes a button to "collapse" itself - hiding its contents and shrinking its height. "collapse" is just what I'm doing now to set its initial value, but it's not my goal - I want to be able to just access all the event-box components after they're in the page and set the "collapsed" property on all but the last of them to "true".